# Modify code to wrap whole words & make it non case sensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function filterSearchWords() {
    var query = $("#searchquery").val();

    go(query);
    function go(query) {
        $(".search-result p:contains(" + query + ")").html(function (_, html) {
            return html.replace(query, "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>", 'gi');
        });
        $(".search-result h2 a:contains(" + query + ")").html(function (_, html) {
            return html.replace(query, "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>", 'gi');
        });
        console.log(query);
    }
}
```

This is my attempt. It adds the span alright, but only to words or part of words that includes the string. Lets say the string is Pie, it adds the span to all "Pie" and wraps "Pie" in Piechart, however I want it to wrap all Piechart, and pie with no capitals.

Can anyone modify my code to help me?

Thanks

My attemption to use the regex "gi" does not seem to be working :/

UPDATE
Almost there...

```
function filterSearchWords() {
    var query = $("#searchquery").val();

    go(query);
    function go(query) {
        $.extend($.expr[':'], {
            'containsi': function (elem, i, match, array) {
                return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
                .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            }
        });

        $(".search-result p:containsi(" + query + ")").html(function (_, html) {
            return html.replace(new RegExp(query,  "gi"), "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>");
        });
        $(".search-result h2 a:containsi(" + query + ")").html(function (_, html) {
            return html.replace(new RegExp(query, "gi"), "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>");
        });
        console.log(query);
    }
}
```

This is my last question. I have succeeded to remove the casesensitive part, but it does not match the entire words.

Answer (score 1):

A note on the third flags parameter from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> Note: The flags argument does not work in v8 Core (Chrome and Node.js)

You should use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object instead:

```
return html.replace(new RegExp(query, "gi"), "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>");
```

Comment: Now it works. see first post. Got 1 more question ;/